# Return relative position on Canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm developing a Windows Store app targeting both tablet and PC.

In my application, I am adding objects to a Canvas via code using SetLeft and SetTop. This method however doesn't return the relative position for different resolutions and the objects end up in the wrong positions.

Also, trying to return the Canvas width returns me NaN. If I could get this then I could work out a relative position.

Is there a way to convert a point into a relative point?

Comment: Can you add some stripped down code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I have a Canvas, and on that Canvas I allow the user to draw with their finger. Their designated path is aligned with a bunch of stars to collect. The stars are added using

Star star = new Star(new Point(212, 707)) - (To be done via XML at a later date)

This is added to the canvas, and its in the right location for the Surface RT. However on a PC, at a different resolution, the stars appear in the wrong place.

Is it possible to use a percentage of a Canvas perhaps? Or is there a relative Point I can use.

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

> Also, trying to return the Canvas width returns me NaN. If I could get this then I could work out a relative position.

You should be able to use [`Canvas.ActualWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) and [`Canvas.ActualHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx) to get the actual width and height at runtime.

Comment: Thanks that did it. I tried ActualWidth and ActualHeight before but that only returned 0. But reading' The default is 0. The default might be encountered if the object has not been loaded and undergone a layout pass.' clears it up.

Comment: @ChrisCook Yes - the ActualWidth is set after the layout occurs - so when the container actually renders the object, it gets set for you.